# Testing Flask login and authentication?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, flask-login, flask-security

I'm developing a Flask application and using Flask-security for user authentication (which in turn uses Flask-login underneath).

I have a route which requires authentication, `/user`. I'm trying to write a unit test which tests that, for an authenticated user, this returns the appropriate response.

In my unittest I'm creating a user and logging as that user like so:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from app import app, db
from models import User
from flask_security.utils import login_user

class UserTest(TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
       self.app = app
       self.client = self.app.test_client()
       self._ctx = self.app.test_request_context()
       self._ctx.push()

       db.create_all()

   def tearDown(self):
       if self._ctx is not None:
           self._ctx.pop()

       db.session.remove()
       db.drop_all()

   def test_user_authentication():
       # (the test case is within a test request context)
       user = User(active=True)
       db.session.add(user)
       db.session.commit()
       login_user(user)

       # current_user here is the user
       print(current_user)

       # current_user within this request is an anonymous user
       r = test_client.get('/user')
```

Within the test `current_user` returns the correct user. However, the requested view always returns an `AnonymousUser` as the `current_user`.

The `/user` route is defined as:

```
class CurrentUser(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return current_user  # returns an AnonymousUser
```

I'm fairly certain I'm just not fully understanding how testing Flask request contexts work. I've read this Flask [Request Context documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/reqcontext/) a bunch but am still not understanding how to approach this particular unit test.

Comment: It would help if you really showed what you were actually doing - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Updated to show how the test is setup.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that the `test_client.get()` call causes a new request context to be pushed, so the one you pushed in your the `setUp()` method of your test case is not the one that the `/user` handler sees.

I think the approach shown in the [Logging In and Out](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/#logging-in-and-out) and [Test Adding Messages](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/#test-adding-messages) sections of the documentation is the best approach for testing logins. The idea is to send the login request through the application, like a regular client would. This will take care of registering the logged in user in the user session of the test client.

Answer (score 35):

**The problem is different request contexts.**

In your normal Flask application, each request creates a new context which will be reused through the whole chain until creating the final response and sending it back to the browser.

When you create and run Flask tests and execute a request (e.g. `self.client.post(...)`) the context is discarded after receiving the response. Therefore, the `current_user` is always an `AnonymousUser`.

To fix this, we have to tell Flask to reuse the same context for the whole test. You can do that by simply wrapping your code with:

```
with self.client:
```

You can read more about this topic in the following wonderful article:
https://realpython.com/blog/python/python-web-applications-with-flask-part-iii/

**Example**

Before:

```
def test_that_something_works():
    response = self.client.post('login', { username: 'James', password: '007' })

    # this will fail, because current_user is an AnonymousUser
    assertEquals(current_user.username, 'James')
```

After:

```
def test_that_something_works():
    with self.client:
        response = self.client.post('login', { username: 'James', password: '007' })

        # success
        assertEquals(current_user.username, 'James')
```

Answer (score 6):

I didn't much like the other solution shown, mainly because you have to keep your password in a unit test file (and I'm using Flask-LDAP-Login, so it's nonobvious to add a dummy user, etc.), so I hacked around it:

In the place where I set up my test app, I added:

```
@app.route('/auto_login')
def auto_login():
    user = ( models.User
             .query
             .filter_by(username="Test User")
             .first() )
    login_user(user, remember=True)
    return "ok"
```

However, I am making quite a lot of changes to the test instance of the flask app, like using a different DB, where I construct it, so adding a route doesn't make the code noticeably messier. Obv this route doesn't exist in the real app.

Then I do:

```
def login(self):
    response = self.app.test_client.get("/auto_login")
```

Anything done after that with `test_client` should be logged in.

Comment: No matter what i try, `current_user` is always AnonymousUser. Any idea how to fix that behavior?

Comment: My guess is that you are not using the `test_client`, or you have some other problem with `request_context` or similar. You have to be very careful with these in testing - make sure you understand what a request context is and be aware of which context you are in.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i got it to work by wrapping my test code in `with self.client:`

Comment: I'm using OpenID for login and this is the only method I could get working while testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It can be convenient to globally turn off authentication when unit testing. To enable this, if the application configuration variable LOGIN_DISABLED is set to True, this decorator will be ignored.