# Testing authenticated endpoints in Flask

Tags: unit-testing, authentication, flask, flask-login, flask-restful

I have a Flask application using LDAP for authentication, with several endpoints managed with flask-restful, but I want to unit test authenticated endpoints *without* actually hitting the LDAP server.  I was hoping to do this by faking flask-login's `current_user` but I have not been able to get this trick to work.  Here is what I've tried:

Endpoints are authenticated because I derive all resources from my own class (this works fine in practice and manual testing, and is what flask-restful recommends):

```
def authenticate(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not getattr(func, 'authenticated', True):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        if flask.ext.login.current_user and flask.ext.login.current_user.is_authenticated():
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        flask.ext.restful.abort(401)
    return wrapper

class AuthenticatedResource(flask.ext.restful.Resource ):
    method_decorators = [authenticate]
```

Here is a simple endpoint:

```
class RootResource(AuthenticatedResource):
    def get(self):
        return {'message':'Hello'}
```

Now in my unit test, I figured I should be able to mock an authenticated user by writing to flask-login's `current_user`:

```
from flask.ext.login import UserMixin, current_user

class AuthenticatedUser(UserMixin):
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
    def is_active(self):
        return True
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False
    def get_id(self):
        return "Test User"

class TestMyAPI(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_root_endpoint_responds_properly(self):
        with app.test_client() as client:
            current_user = AuthenticatedUser()
            response = client.get('/')
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
            body = json.loads(response.data)
            self.assertEqual(body, {'message':'Hello'})
```

Unfortunately the test responds with a failure:

```
==================================================================
FAIL: test_root_endpoint_responds_properly (test_my_api.TestMyAPI)
------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxx/test_graph_api.py", line xxx, in test_root_endpoint_responds_properly
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 401 != 200
```

Other notes: I am using flask 0.9, not 0.10.  I am aware of [Miguel Grinberg's answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21506945) but I don't actually want to invoke a login; I want to bypass the use of LDAP (or any test database) completely.

Why does the `current_user` override trick not work?  Is there some other approach I should be using?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the code in the question does not work is that the line

```
current_user = AuthenticatedUser()
```

creates a new local variable called `current_user`.  This is not the same as `flask.ext.login.current_user`.

That line should be changed to:

```
flask.ext.login.current_user = AuthenticatedUser()
```