# Getting Flask-Login to work with unittest

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest, flask-login

I know logins are disabled by default in testing. I'm trying to get them back on, by setting `app.config['LOGIN_DISABLED']` to False. This doesn't seem to be working, since `current_user` still returns `None`, but will return a User in code outside a test file.

Some relevant bits of code are below. My Flask app object is originally created in my app's main `__init__.py`, which is imported and re-configured during testing.

===========

## **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config[u'DEBUG'] = settings.debug
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
```

===========

## tests/base.py

```
from my_app import app, db
import unittest

class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    app.config['LOGIN_DISABLED'] = False
    #app.login_manager._login_disabled = False #doesn't help either
    self.app = app.test_client()
    db.create_all()
```

===========

## tests/test_a.py

```
from flask_login import current_user
from my_app.tests.base import BaseTest

class MyTests(BaseTest):
  def test_a(self):
    #visit endpoint that calls `login_user(user)`
    #printing `current_user` in that endpoint works, but the following line only returns `None`
    print current_user
```

Note: The User should definitely be logged in before the print statement. Using `current_user` in the endpoint works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out my problem was due to testing not using the same context, so my solution is similar to what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506326/testing-flask-login-and-authentication/28816040#28816040) and [here](https://realpython.com/python-web-applications-with-flask-part-iii/#run-the-test). `tests/test_a.py` now looks like:

```
from flask_login import current_user
from my_app.tests.base import BaseTest

class MyTests(BaseTest):
  def test_a(self):
    with self.app:
      print current_user
```

Strangely, `app.config['LOGIN_DISABLED'] = False` and `app.login_manager._login_disabled = False` don't matter after this change - both can be removed.